# How to build this project from github?

Tags: android, github

I want to build the project in [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development) link in Android studio.How to do that?
Can I load all sample apps in it as a whole or should I load each one separately?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=build+aosp

Comment: @leoderprofi Can you explain that? Couldn't understand it.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . First step is search and research, I think you missed that step.

Comment: @leoderprofi I have been searching for this answer for a very long time.I am still a beginner, so couldn't find an understandable solution till now

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to prepare your build environment: https://source.android.com/setup/initializing

Than you either proceed building image for specific device:
https://source.android.com/setup/building#choose-a-target

Or build Android SDK: http://tools.android.com/build